# CRM Cannot obtain lock on resource when adding OpportunityProduct

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a plugin on OpportunityProduct that calculates the tax for the item when it is created or updated. Most of the time it works fine but when I add a number of products programatically it sometimes fails with the exception below.

The new Opportunity Product exists in the database when the exception is thrown and the row it's trying to lock is the one that was added just before it. I believe what is happening is that I add a new product then CRM retrieves all of the products for the opportunity to calculate the totals. I don't know what mechanism is used to update the totals. It's not a regular plugin and I have no way to even see what it's doing let alone change it.

This is an on-premise installation of CRM 2011 with rollup 15(v2).

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Bill

Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.SaveChangesException: An error occured while processing this request. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: Cannot obtain lock on resource:'OpportunityProduct_dbe8cb25-031c-e411-8f23-002269c5d599', mode:Update - stored procedure sp_getapplock returned error code -3.
Result StackTrace:

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.<>c__DisplayClass19.<Execute>b__18(IOrganizationService s)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.InnerOrganizationService.UsingService[TResult](Func`2 action)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.CachedOrganizationService.InnerExecute(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationServiceCache.InnerExecute[TRequest,TResponse,TResult](TRequest query, Func`2 execute, Func`2 selector)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationServiceCache.InnerExecute[TRequest,TResponse,TResult](TRequest request, Func`2 execute, Func`2 selector, String selectorCacheKey)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationServiceCache.Execute[T](OrganizationRequest request, Func`2 execute, Func`2 selector, String selectorCacheKey)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.CachedOrganizationService.Execute[T](OrganizationRequest request, Func`5 execute, Func`2 selector, String selectorCacheKey)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.CachedOrganizationService.Execute[T](OrganizationRequest request, Func`2 selector, String selectorCacheKey)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.CachedOrganizationService.Execute[T](OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.CachedOrganizationService.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmOrganizationServiceContext.Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.Execute(OrganizationRequest )
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChange(OrganizationRequest request, IList`1 results)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChanges()
   at RenewalUnitTests.CrmTest.CreateProposalServiceCode(Guid proposalId, String serviceCodeNumber, String servicePeriodNumber, String servicePeriodNumber2, Int32 quantity, String uomName) in c:\Code\ktfs1\Projects\CRM\DEV\Renewal\RenewalUnitTests\CrmTest.cs:line 373
   at BridgestoneUnitTests.BridgestoneTests.EmailSimpleProposal() in c:\Code\ktfs1\Projects\CRM\DEV\Renewal\RenewalUnitTests\BridgestoneTests.cs:line 190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up moving the tax calculation elsewhere and removing the plugin on OpportunityProduct. This caused the locking issue to go away. Unfortunately I had to duplicate the code in a couple of places since it got called multiple ways.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of pipeline stage do you use in your plugin? Try to change it to "Pre-operation".
(Do you update some other entities in that plugin?)

Or (if it possible by business logic) change execution mode to "Asynchronous".

Comment: It is running in the pre-operation stage. Sorry I didn't specify this. I originally had it in post-op but ran into even more locking issues. Async is not an option. The tax must appear when the form refreshes.